# How to separate solr/home and data/dir in Catalina/localhost XML file?

Tags: debian, configuration, tomcat, solr, xml

I've the following configuration file within `conf/Catalina/localhost` in Tomcat 7:

```
<Context docBase="webapps/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr/home" override="true" />
   <Environment name="data/dir" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/lib/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

where I would like to separate my `solr.home` from `data.dir`.

I've tested the above config files, but doesn't seems to work.

Is it something possible using that this kind of XML configuration file?

I've checked on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Environment%20name%22%20%22solr.data.dir%22&type=Code&ref=searchresults) and there are some configuration files which they have it there, but I couldn't make it working.

Comment: Is that helps ? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Multiple_Solr_apps

Comment: @krisFR Thanks, however it doesn't help, I've seen that already, but it doesn't show if I can define `data/dir` (I'm not sure even if the name of variable is correct). Basically I want to have one instance, but two different folders to separate config files and data it-self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use [Tomcat context environment entries](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Environment_Entries) for data directory without patching Solr. It seems only `solr/home` variable works fine.

The better way of doing is by using JVM system property file (`solrcore.properties`) which should be located either within your Solr `conf/` home directory (or: `collection1/conf`) or Tomcat `WEB-INF/` dir with the following entry:

```
solr.data.dir=/var/lib/solr
```

by using and reload your app or restart your Tomcat service to reload Java properties.

Alternatively is to use `solr.xml` (in Solr 4.x) by setting different `instanceDir` and `dataDir` which would separate `dataDir` from the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't believe so.
>
> Work was done a long time ago to support system property substitution
>   when  the `solrconfig.xml` file is loaded, but i don't think that was
>   ever  generalized to support JNDI values as well (which is the
>   `<Environment/>`  tags in context files set).
>
> I actually have a patch for solr config parser which allows you to use
>   context environment variables in the `solrconfig.xml`.

Posted by [Chris Hostetter](http://grokbase.com/user/Chris-Hostetter/PVVdPRPmwqsH69svihXecR) (Hoss) back in 2010 at [solr-user group](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/1056n9zh9p/any-way-to-specify-the-data-dir-in-tomcat-context-file).